# PythonWin's python interactive shell calling constructors twice?

Tags: python, python-2.x, activestate

While answering [Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/python-static-variable#81002)

I noticed that PythonWin PyWin32 build 209.2 interpreter seems to evaluate twice?

```
PythonWin 2.5 (r25:51908, Mar  9 2007, 17:40:28) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32.
Portions Copyright 1994-2006 Mark Hammond - see 'Help/About PythonWin' for further copyright information.
>>> class X:
...     l = []
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.__class__.l.append(1)
...         
>>> X().l
[1, 1]
>>>
```

while the python interpreter does the right thing

```
C:\>python
ActivePython 2.5.0.0 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.5 (r25:51908, Mar  9 2007, 17:40:28) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class X:
...   l = []
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.__class__.l.append(1)
...
>>> X().l
[1]
>>>
```

Comment: @Gregory, this seems more like a bug report for PyWin than a SO question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is as follows.  The PythonWin editor offers autocomplete for an object, i.e. when you type `myobject.` it offers a little popup of all the availble method names.  So I think when you type `X().` it's creating an instance of `X` in the background and doing a `dir` or similar to find out the attributes of the object.

So the constructor is only being run *once for each object* but to give you the interactivity it's creating objects silently in the background without telling you about it.

Answer (score 2):

Dave Webb is correct, and you can see this by adding a print statement:

```
>>> class X:
...     l = []
...     def __init__(self):
...             print 'inited'
...             self.__class__.l.append(1)
...
```

Then as soon as you type the period in `X().` it prints `inited` prior to offering you the completion popup.

Answer (score 1):

Two small additional points.

First, `self.__class__.l.append(1)` isn't really sensible.

Just say `self.l.append(1)`.  Python searches the instance before it searches the class for the reference.

More importantly, class-level variables are rarely useful.  Class-level constants are sometimes sensible, but even then, they're hard to justify.

In C++ and Java, class-level ('`static`') variables seem handy, but don't do much of value.  They're hard to teach to n00bz -- often wasting lots of classroom time on minutia -- and they aren't very practical.  If you want to know all instances of an X that was created, it's probably better to create an XFactory class that doesn't rely on class variables.

```
class XFactory( object ):
    def __init__( self ):
        self.listOfX= []
    def makeX( self, *args, **kw ):
        newX= X(*args,**kw)
        self.listOfX.append(newX)
        return newX
```

No class-level variable anomalies.  And, it doesn't conflate the X's with the collection of X's.  In the long run, I find it confusing when a class is both some thing and also some collection of things.

Simpler is better than Complex.

Comment: If you look at my post I was answering the static question attached. So I want to specifically change the class variable and not the instance variable. The code I wrote is the "cleanest" way to explicitly access class variables.